# Understanding custom policies in stable-baselines3

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I was trying to understand the policy networks in stable-baselines3 from this [doc page](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/custom_policy.html).

1. As explained in [this](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/custom_policy.html#custom-feature-extractor) example, to specify **custom CNN feature extractor**, we extend `BaseFeaturesExtractor` class and specify it in `policy_kwarg.features_extractor_class` with first param `CnnPolicy`:

   ```
   model = PPO("CnnPolicy", "BreakoutNoFrameskip-v4", policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs)
   ```

   **Q1.** Can we follow same approach for **custom MLP feature extractor**?
2. As explained in [this](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/custom_policy.html#advanced-example) example, to specify **custom MLP feature extractor**, we extend `ActorCriticPolicy` class and [override](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/c62e9259db363bf32bd920405dbe83db94123271/stable_baselines3/common/policies.py#L459) `_build_mlp_extractor()` and pass it as first param:

   ```
   class CustomActorCriticPolicy(ActorCriticPolicy): ...
   model = PPO(CustomActorCriticPolicy, "CartPole-v1", verbose=1)
   ```

   **Q2.** Can we follow same approach for **custom CNN feature extractor**?
3. I feel either we can have CNN extractor or MLP extractor. So it makes no sense to pass `MlpPolicy` as first param to model and then specify CNN feature extractor in `policy_kwarg.features_extractor_class` as in [this](https://www.kaggle.com/toshikazuwatanabe/connect4-make-submission-with-stable-baselines3) example. This result in following policy (containing both `features_extractor` and `mlp_extractor`), which I feel is incorrect:

   ```
   ActorCriticPolicy(
     (features_extractor): Net(
       (conv1): Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
       (conv2): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
       (fc3): Linear(in_features=384, out_features=512, bias=True)
     )
     (mlp_extractor): MlpExtractor(
       (shared_net): Sequential(
         (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=64, bias=True)
         (1): ReLU()
       )
       (policy_net): Sequential(
         (0): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=32, bias=True)
         (1): ReLU()
         (2): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=16, bias=True)
         (3): ReLU()
       )
       (value_net): Sequential(
         (0): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=32, bias=True)
         (1): ReLU()
         (2): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=16, bias=True)
         (3): ReLU()
       )
     )
     (action_net): Linear(in_features=16, out_features=7, bias=True)
     (value_net): Linear(in_features=16, out_features=1, bias=True)
   )
   ```

   **Q3.** Am I correct with this understanding? If yes, then is one of the MLP or CNN feature extractor ignored?

Answer (score 3):

What I can say after i went through all the library code. `CnnPolicy` is differ to `MlpPolicy` only in implemented default `BaseFeatureExtraction` class. This make sense only in a case when you are not trying to create your custom `BaseFeatureExtraction` class.
Let me try to explain, we can see two types of policies:

```
MlpPolicy = ActorCriticPolicy
CnnPolicy = ActorCriticCnnPolicy
```

And we can see that `class ActorCriticCnnPolicy(ActorCriticPolicy)`is just based on `ActorCriticPolicy` and we can see following in parameters:

```
features_extractor_class: Type[BaseFeaturesExtractor] = NatureCNN
```

where `NatureCNN` is a simple implementation of `BaseFeatureExtractor` with CNN layers.

Now lets move to your **questions**!
Here is one thing, we always have following structure of model:
*FeatureExtractor* -> *MlpExtractor* -> *Policy\Value nets*

You can specify `feature_exctractor_class` and `net_arch` in policy_kwargs.
Default feature_extractor_class is based on your selection of `CnnPolicy` or `MlpPolicy`, but if you specify your own class then there is no difference. So, you can just use `MlpPolicy`.

If you specify `net_arch`, for example `'net_arch':[64, dict(pi=[32, 16], vf=[32, 16])]` you will have 1 dense layer for mlp_extractor that connects output from feature_extractor.

To summary, my suggestion is to **follow** the example that you found in your **Q3**.:

1. Specify your own `feature_extractor` with any structure of this network either cnn or dense or whatever you want. The output of `feature_extractor` should be FC layer.
2. Specify `net_acrh` parameter in the following structure: `[x1, x2, ..., dict(pi=[px1, px2, ..], vf=[vx1, vx2, ...])]` where the first part is specified size of FC layers for `mlp_extractor` and the second part (inside dict) corresponds to sizes of policy and value networks.